# autoCAD running commands from c#

Tags: c#, autocad

I want to execute autoCAD command at c#.
I want to apply the "JUSTIFYTEXT MC" command to the selected object after clicking the button.
Currently my code can be executed in command, but a new autoCAD window will be executed.
I want to know how to run the command in the CAD window that is currently running.

My Code

```
AcadApplication acad = new AcadApplication();

acad.Visible = true;
acad.WindowState = AcWindowState.acMin;
acad.ActiveDocument.SendCommand("JUSTIFYTEXT MC ");
```

Comment: It's getting a new AutoCAD window because you're creating a new `AcadApplication`. You need to connect to the existing AcadApplication instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Can you tell me how to connect to an existing AcadApplication?
I don't know how to...

Comment: Just load your module so you can run your application. And change your code to use the existing autocad instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by creating a bundle that is loaded by the autoloader and creating a `Web Api`.

Bundle: https://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/01/autodesk-autoloader-white-paper.html

A bundle is a folder located on for example `C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins` that has a certain structure, what `Autodesk` products the bundle supports, platform (`Win32`, `Win64` and where the start point for your bundle is. This config should be within a `PackageContents.xml` at the root.

A content folder on the same level as `PackageContents.xml` containing all your dlls etc.

These dlls can be loaded on startup when configuring `PackageContents.xml` correctly and using the interface `IExtensionApplication`.

In the class that extends the `IExtensionApplication` interface you can create a `Web Api` or some other kind of communication like `SignalR` when `Initialize()` is called. Save the connection string to a file and read it from your other application.

You should now have the ability to communicate with a running `AutoCAD` instance through a local web api hosted within that `AutoCAD` instance.

Hope that brief explanation helped.